# In layman's terms, does the Luckstone just give a passive +1 to all d20 rolls and saves except for death saves?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

The description of the [*stone of good luck* (or *luckstone*)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/stone-of-good-luck-luckstone) says:

> While this polished agate is on your person, you gain a +1 bonus to ability checks and saving throws.

In layman's terms, does the *luckstone* just give a passive +1 to all d20 rolls and saves except for death saves?

Because as far as I can see, all almost all d20 rolls have an ability tied to them to make a check or opposed check. The only one I can think of that does not use an ability with the d20 roll is death saves.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are four types of d20 rolls in 5e:

- Ability Checks,
- Saving Throws,
- Attack Rolls,
- Miscellaneous (everything else).

The *Stone of Good Luck* gives its bonus to the first two - this includes [death save throws](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#DeathSavingThrows) because they are saving throws and [Initiative](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Initiative) because it is a dexterity ability check. It also gives its bonus to [passive](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#PassiveChecks) ability checks like passive Wisdom (Perception) because they are ability checks.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that there is a 4th kind? "Stand-alone" rolls that aren't tied to an ability score. Such as the d20 roll to see if your Wand of Fireballs dies if you expend its final charge...the Stone of Good Luck wouldn't help there either.

Comment: To clarify, this is an uncommon magic item that for the price of an attunement slot, gives you +1 in 18 skills, 7 saving throws (including death), passive perception/investigation, and initiative?  That's +28 in increases across your whole character, or am I misinterpreting this?

Comment: @bubbajake00 It's not really correct to add all of those bonuses together, but it does indeed do all the things you just listed. It is quite powerful, but keep in mind "rarity" isn't really a good indicator of powerlevel.

Comment: @Cubic "'rarity' isn't really a good indicator of powerlevel." One of my big problems with D&D5, succinctly explained.

Answer (score 14):

No.  It does not include attack rolls, which are done with a d20. Attack rolls are distinct from ability checks and saving throws; they are their own type of roll, even though they include a modifier associated with an ability.

It *does* give its bonus to death saves, however, which are saving throws even though they are not associated with an ability.

Comment: What about Initiative rolls?

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver it is an ability check roll, so it benefits from +1 from Luckstone.